# Rebalancing executors in Apache Storm

Tags: apache-storm

I am trying to rebalance the number of executors for a bolt in a running Apache Storm (0.9.5) topology. When I execute the command to the Nimbus node `./storm rebalance MyTopology -n 2 -e GreenBolt=4` it accepts the command line input but the number of executors is not changed when I view in the Storm UI.

Is there a limitation that I'm not aware of like a rebalance can not increase the total number of executors and only move them from one bolt to another?

Comment: Read here: https://storm.apache.org/documentation/Understanding-the-parallelism-of-a-Storm-topology.html Did you set number of tasks high enough when deploying your topology?

Comment: Thanks Matthias. I read the documentation but I didn't realize that you needed to set a high number of tasks. "The number of tasks for a component is always the same throughout the lifetime of a topology, but the number of executors (threads) for a component can change over time." I guess that supports your answer. I'll have a go. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You always need to have more (or equal number of) tasks than executors. As the number of tasks is fixed, you need to set a larger initial number than initial executors in order to be able to scale up the number of executors during runtime. You can see the number of tasks, as maximum number of executors:

```
#executors <= #numTasks
```

See here for details: https://storm.apache.org/documentation/Understanding-the-parallelism-of-a-Storm-topology.html

Comment: so there is no way to have some kind of dynamic task duplication in storm?(to be able to add more tasks at runtime) 
isn't it implemented yet or it can't be done?
Asked the question here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42487777/add-tasks-dynamically-at-runtime-in-apache-storm

Comment: It's not possible.