# Override storm.yaml / setting in Java bolts/spouts

Tags: apache-storm

Need help with Tuning apache storm. I have run a command on the nimbus server to increase the spout executors & and a for a bolt.

My question is simple. Does the command:

**storm rebalance TopologyName -e spout/or/bolt=**

Does this override number of parallel hints in the Java code ?

I ran this and did not see a change in the web GUI interface.

Also is there a way to override the parameter in the storm.yaml file ?

**topology.max.spout.pending: 1000**

Thanks for any help on this. I do have an excellent book on Storm but I cannot find out why my changes are not being reflected after rebalance...

Answer (score 1):

Did you set the number of tasks high enough? See here for further details:

1. [Rebalancing executors in Apache Storm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31932573/rebalancing-executors-in-apache-storm/31941796#31941796)
2. https://storm.apache.org/documentation/Understanding-the-parallelism-of-a-Storm-topology.html

So yes, it does override the parallel hint, **but only if applicable**.

And yes, you can use `storm.yaml` to set the *default* "max pending" parameter. This value can be changed for each topology individually by overwriting the default value in the configuration you provide for a topology when submitting it:

```
Config conf = new Config();
conf.setMaxSpoutPending( /* put your value here */ );
StormSubmitter.submitTopology("topologyName", conf, builder.createTopology());
```

Comment: yes he can set the "default" topology.max.spout.pending on storm.yaml https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/master/conf/defaults.yaml